# Navigating to a new view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to correctly navigate to a new view?

App:

- TabNavigator (Top of the screen)
- StackNavigator (Bottom of the screen)

I want that after choosing a button from StackNavigator opened a new screen that will override the entire application. I do not want to see TabNavigator and StackNavigator.

In the new window, I want it to be NavBar with the return button

All the tutorials that I'm watching show how to switch between screens but I can not find the situation above.

I want to open a new window from the main application and then return to it

EDITED:

```
const TopNavTabs = TabNavigator({
  General: { screen: General },
  Help: { screen: Help },
  Tips: { screen: Tips },
}
});

export const Navigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Tab: { screen: TopNavTabs },
    Article: { screen: Article },
  }
);

export default class App extends Component{

  render(){
      return(
          <View>
            <View>
              <Navigation navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            </View>
            <View>
              <View>
                <MCIcon name="account"/>
              </View>
              <View>
                <MIcon name="create" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Article')} />
              </View>
              <View>
                <FAIcon name="hashtag" />  
              </View>
              <View>
                <FAIcon name="search" />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `TabNavigator` in `StackNavigator` like:

```
const TopNavTabs = TabNavigator(
  {
   General: { screen: General },
      Help: { screen: Help },
      Tips: { screen: Tips },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }
);

    export const Navigation = StackNavigator(
      {
        Tab: { screen: TopNavTabs },
        Article: { screen: Article },
      }
    );



    export default class App extends Component{

      render(){
          return(

                  <Navigation  />

          )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I have an error now `_this2.props.navigation.navigate`

Comment: Can you share cod with me?

Comment: Your class App not in navigation so this.props.navigation is not available here.

Comment: And does this mean that in each tab I need to add the bottom bar with buttons again? And the second thing is it possible to get rid of the first page of the bar on which the title shows itself on the posts? At the first there is no way to go back and the title is not needed.

Comment: At the moment I have at the top `TabNavigator` and at the bottom of the panel created using `<View>`.  Do I have to create a new `TabNavigator` instead of what I have at the bottom, which will have `swipeEnable` off? Should it work correctly?

Comment: I think you must use TabBarBottom and customize it.

Comment: Do you know how to hide Header in the first photo? The second one is ok because we have a button to return to the previous page.  `navigationOptions: {header: null}` hides everywhere so I'm looking for another solution

Comment: I have added photos to your answer by mistake. I can change this

Comment: As a last resort, I can turn it off and create it and add it to every new screen. But should it be so?

Comment: Yes, you create your header.